# What's the name of this colorful tiny spider?

Tags: arachnology

Found this colorful spider yesterday in my study. Couldn't find exact match over internet. Does anyone know what spider is this? Is it harmful?[image: colorful jumping spider]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions should also include: 1) the species-identification tag; 2) the location where you observed this organism (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better); 3) habitat information; and 4) an estimate of the size of the organism. Please [edit] your post to include this essential information. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Answer (score 5):

It seems a lot like the 'jade jumping spider'.

The jade jumping spider scientifically known as *Siler semiglaucus* has been observed primarily in Asia. I notice that the legs and abdomen have similar patterns to this species. As for the feelers and head I'm not so sure, but the dark hair on the front legs makes me more convinced of my guess. Perhaps look at different species that share the same genus to see if there is any other species that looks more similar to your observation.

[image: Siler semiglaucus]
[image]
[image]

If you're still not convinced, as a last resort, perhaps take a look at the peacock spider also known as *Maratus volans*. It's a long shot but maybe you see connections that I couldn't catch from the photo :).

Comment: Thank you for the details, Ark. 